# How to use MSBuild to xcopy only modified or new files recursively?

Tags: msbuild

I need some help using MSBuild to xcopy files to two directories.

First I found out about [Sayed's](http://sedodream.com/2010/10/22/MSBuildExtendingTheSolutionBuild.aspx) after.xyz.sln.targets.  This will ensure that copy file tasks will run regardless of actual Build occurs or not.

I wanted to use that to copy only new or modified only files to two target directories.  So I need some sort of comparison code also.  Steps that I can think of.

1. compare dir1 to dir2 and find any new or modified files in dir1.
2. copy those files to dir2 recursively.
3. then copy the exact file sets to dir3 recursively.

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a parameter `SkipUnchangedFiles` of the [Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) task. Example:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup>
        <MySourceFiles Include="c:\MySourceTree\**\*.*"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="CopyFiles">
        <Copy
            SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"
            DestinationFiles="@(MySourceFiles->'c:\MyDestinationTree\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
            SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
        />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I sure didn't know about SkipUnchangedFiles.  Is there a way for me to specify c:\MyDestinationTree to be from ItemGroup?  I tried @(MyTarget) but it actually creates folder like the Item name.

Comment: @sdog, I am not sure I understand correctly your second question in the comment. Please open up a new question for that and describe your scenario in more details.